# Creating a New List Using a Percent Amount of a Pre-existing One - Python

Tags: python, list, percentage

Essentially, I have to take a pre-existing list and a percentage and return a new list with the given percentage of items from the first list in a new list. I have what follows:

```
def select_stop_words(percent, list):
    possible_stop_words = []
    l = len(list)
    new_words_list = l//(percent/100)
    x = int(new_words_list - 1)
    possible_stop_words = [:x]
    return possible_stop_words
```

But this always yields the same results as the first. Help??

Answer (score 0):

You might want to *multiply* `l` to `percent / 100`:

```py
def select_stop_words(percent, lst):
    return lst[:len(lst) * percent // 100]

lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
print(select_stop_words(50, lst)) # [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
print(select_stop_words(20, lst)) # [1, 2]
print(select_stop_words(99, lst)) # [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
print(select_stop_words(100, lst)) # [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```